# Set first character in a string to uppercase

Tags: java, string, jtextfield

I want to change the first character to uppercase in a textfield.

I have this:

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

And this:

```
String output = Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0)) + input.substring(1);
```

Where should I put those? `keyPressed`? `keyReleased`?
Please tell me how to use those.

Comment: Try to use `addFocusListener`

Comment: Do you want to be automatic or when you press a key for example?

Comment: Automatic or after I typed.

Comment: @user3337385 well then use `DocumentFilter` i don't know why you don't want to use it.. give me a reason

Comment: @user3337385 Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Use DocumentFilter to intercept user's input and replace it with desired chars

E.g.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/FormatJTextFieldstexttouppercase.htm

Comment: I don't want to use DocumentFilter

Comment: @user3337385 why not? then extend `PlainDocument` and override `insertString`

Comment: It's because I can't use it. I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of `addFocusListener`;

```
jTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
      public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        //TODO: write here what you want 
      }
});
```

Comment: So, I should put it on FocusListener?

Comment: This code even compile.. use FocusAdapter then, but i don't recommend to use this solution..

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when we type names, we should enter the first letter of the name in Uppercase shape. So, in this case, I have solved the problem as shown in below code segment:

```
private void jTextFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (!Character.isAlphabetic(evt.getKeyChar()) && !Character.isSpaceChar(evt.getKeyChar())) {
        evt.consume();
    } else if (jTextField.getText().trim().length() == 0 && Character.isLowerCase(evt.getKeyChar())) {
            evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(evt.getKeyChar()));
    }
}
```